# Parse a value from the json

Tags: json, jq, jmespath

I have a following json

```json
{
  "kind":"testObject",
  "spec":{
  },
  "status":{
    "code":"503"
  }
}
```

I would like to just retrieve the value of code, so that it would just show `503` as an output.

I did try with JMESPath, but that binary is out of question, and not sure what to use.

Comment: Try `jq --raw-output '.status.code'`

Comment: What do you mean by _"that binary is out of question"_?

Answer (score 1):

Access the value with `.status.code`:

```
$ jq '.status.code' <<JSON
{
 "kind":"testObject",
 "spec":{
 },
 "status":{
  "code":"503"
 }
}
JSON
"503"
```

If you want your output to be `503` (as compared to `"503"`), use `--raw-output`/`-r`:

```
$ jq -r '.status.code' <<JSON
{
 "kind":"testObject",
 "spec":{
 },
 "status":{
  "code":"503"
 }
}
JSON
503
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this question has the [jmespath](/questions/tagged/jmespath) tag, it is worth pointing out that one could use the JMESPATH command-line tool, jp, as follows:

```
jp status.code
```

or to suppress the quotation marks:

```
jp -u status.code
```

Similarly, using jaq, which has a jq-based syntax, one could write:

```
jaq .status.code
```

or to suppress the quotation marks:

```
jaq -r .status.code
```